# Custom button that takes user to edit page

Tags: custom-link, detail

I want to create a custom button, which when clicked, diverts the user to a page that allows them to enter a new Call__c record.
I cannot find the right syntax for this anymore, but it was something like this: `{!Call__c.Id}/e}`.
Tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you have shared is to open an existing record in edit page. To create a new record, you would need to use the object's prefix. You can open any of the Call__c existing records to check the prefix. The prefix is the first 3 characters of the ID. E.g. the ID of your call records are something like `a0AJ0000008****` then the prefix would be `a0A`. The syntax for the custom button would then be

```
/a0A/e
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, `{!URLFOR($Action.Call__c.Edit, Call__c.Id, [id=Call__c.Id], true}` should work in most cases.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Right. I upvoted your comment.